# Android CustomAdapter stops evaluating if statement on scrolling in listview android

Tags: android, listview

i have custom adapter for list view , i have if statement in it . when i run the app the view that i can see is working good and the if statement is working , but ones i scroll down the new list item will not go throw the if statement , anyway when i scroll up back the old item will also not go to throw the if statement ,

```
package my.penta.dumpster.dumpster.m_UI;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import my.penta.dumpster.dumpster.R;
import my.penta.dumpster.dumpster.app.AppConfig;
import my.penta.dumpster.dumpster.helper.SQLiteHandler;
import my.penta.dumpster.dumpster.m_DataObject.Spacecraft;

/**
 * Created by Zezo2 on 7/24/2017.
 */

public class CustomAdapterHistoryMonthleyNonrecy extends BaseAdapter {
    private SQLiteHandler db;
    Context c;
    String urlAddress;
    ArrayList<Spacecraft> spacecrafts;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private static final String TAG = CustomAdapterHistoryMonthleyNonrecy.class.getSimpleName();
    String zero = "0";
    public CustomAdapterHistoryMonthleyNonrecy(Context c, ArrayList<Spacecraft> spacecrafts,String urlAddress) {
        this.c = c;
        this.spacecrafts = spacecrafts;
        inflater= (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.urlAddress = urlAddress;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return spacecrafts.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return spacecrafts.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.model_monthely_history_nonrecy,parent,false);
        }
        TextView nametxt= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView branchnumb= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact);
        TextView numboftrip= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView43);

        TextView trip1= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t1);//28
        TextView type1= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t2);//28
        TextView qua1= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t3);//28
        TextView price1= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t4);//28

        TextView trip2= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t11);//28
        TextView type2= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t22);//28
        TextView qua2= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t33);//28
        TextView price2= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t44);//28

        TextView trip3= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t111);//28
        TextView type3= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t222);//28
        TextView qua3= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t333);//28
        TextView price3= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t444);//28

        TextView trip4= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t1111);//28
        TextView type4= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t2222);//28
        TextView qua4= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t3333);//28
        TextView price4= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t4444);//28

        TextView trip5= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t11111);//28
        TextView type5= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t22222);//28
        TextView qua5= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t33333);//28
        TextView price5= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t44444);//28

        TextView trip6= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t111111);//28
        TextView type6= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t222222);//28
        TextView qua6= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t333333);//28
        TextView price6= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t444444);//28

        TextView trip7= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t1111111);//28
        TextView type7= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t2222222);//28
        TextView qua7= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t3333333);//28
        TextView price7= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t4444444);//28

        TableRow row1 = (TableRow) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row2); // this is the first row
        TableRow row2 = (TableRow) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row3); // this is the first row
        TableRow row3 = (TableRow) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row4); // this is the first row
        TableRow row4 = (TableRow) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row5); // this is the first row
        TableRow row5 = (TableRow) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row6); // this is the first row
        TableRow row6 = (TableRow) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row7); // this is the first row
        TableRow row7 = (TableRow) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row8); // this is the first row



       // ImageView img= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.movieImage);
        //BIND DATA
        final Spacecraft s= (Spacecraft) this.getItem(position);

        if (urlAddress.equals(AppConfig.URL_Dailyhistory)) {

            nametxt.setText("Date : "+s.getName()+"/"+s.getContent()+"/"+s.getPrice3());
        }else
        {
            nametxt.setText("Month : "+s.getName()+"/"+s.getContent());
        }





        branchnumb.setText("total Price : "+s.getQuantity());
        numboftrip.setText("number of trip : "+s.getUserid());

        Log.d(TAG, "Garden Waste "+s.getProvince());

        if (s.getProvince().equals(zero))
        {
           row1.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        }else
        {
            trip1.setText(s.getProvince());
            type1.setText("Garden Waste");
            qua1.setText(s.getTotal_lorry_price_all());
            price1.setText(s.getBintype());
        }

        //hardcore

        if (s.getDate().equals(zero))
        {
            row2.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        }else
        {
            trip2.setText(s.getDate());
            type2.setText("Hardcore");
            qua2.setText(s.getLorry_price());
            price2.setText(s.getRecyclable_grading_weight_matching());
        }


        if (s.getTime().equals(zero))
        {
            row3.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        }else
        {
            trip3.setText(s.getTime());
            type3.setText("Cooked Food Waste");
            qua3.setText(s.getOrderid());
            price3.setText(s.getPlacement_update());
        }

        ////////

        if (s.getRectype().equals(zero))
        {
            row4.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        }else
        {
            trip4.setText(s.getRectype());
            type4.setText("Fresh Meat");
            qua4.setText(s.getCode());
            price4.setText(s.getFilling_update());
        }

        ////////

        if (s.getType1().equals(zero))
        {
            row5.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        }else
        {
            trip5.setText(s.getType1());
            type5.setText("Wooden Waste");
            qua5.setText(s.getTotal_price());
            price5.setText(s.getCollection_update());
        }

        ////////

        if (s.getLorry_type().equals(zero))
        {
            row6.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        }else
        {
            trip6.setText(s.getLorry_type());
            type6.setText("Plastic Waste");
            qua6.setText(s.getPer_kg());
            price6.setText(s.getDisposal_update());
        }
////////
        if (s.getFrq().equals(zero))
        {
            row7.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        }else
        {
            trip7.setText(s.getFrq());
            type7.setText("Mix Waste");
            qua7.setText(s.getTotal_loading_fee());
            price7.setText(s.getIntOrderDone());
        }



        db = new SQLiteHandler(c);


        //IMG
       // PicassoClient.downloadImage(c,s.getImageUrl(),img);



        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });


        return convertView;
    }

    private void openDetailACtivity(String name, String branchnumber, int rowid,String userid){





    }




}
```

when i run the app if i scroll down to the end and then up again all the if statement will run . `rowANY.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Comment: Are you sure you want 7 rows per adapter? Are you not trying to have 7 rows in list view?

Comment: yeah i need 7 row each row content 4 textview in each adapter not 7 row in list view , this row is for TableRow its nothing to do with the listview

Comment: You're not setting them to `VISIBLE` again in the `else` block. Add `rowANY.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` in all the `else`s.

Comment: Views are recycled when the list is scrolled. You must handle rowANY.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); in else condition also for all views visibility, text you change in if must have default state in else

Comment: @MikeM. + Pavan . That's work perfectly , Thank you so Much